# How to authenticate Fitbit user with OAuth 2.0?

Tags: python, api, oauth, oauth-2.0, fitbit

I am trying to write a web application with Python using the Fitbit API. I need to authenticate the user with OAuth 2.0 in the browser. Right now I'm trying to use [python-fitbit](https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit), though I'm not sure there's a better way to do this. Here is my code:

```
import fitbit
client = fitbit.FitbitOauth2Client('client_id', 'client_secret')
res = client.make_request("https://api.fitbit.com/1/user/-/activities.json", None, method='GET')
```

When I run it, I get `ValueError: Missing access token.` What am I doing wrong here? I feel totally in over my head with this.

Comment: there is a fitbit class that fetches the activities data. Have you checked out the documentation?

Answer (score 0):

Did you notice this known bug in python-fitbit?

https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit/issues/70

Seems like it might be what you're hitting. That user described a workaround in using another fitbit python client.

Edit:
Adding quote from other article for a better answer!

> As I successfully obtain my token using another Fitbit API client (https://github.com/magnific0/FitBit.py), it seems there is a problem
>   with your script "gather_keys_oauth2.py".
>
> I would say that oauthlib call using OAuth2Session should not try to
>   validate the token during the request phase.

Comment: A link to a potential solution is always welcome, but please add context around the link so your fellow users will have some idea what it is and why it’s there. Always quote the most relevant part of an important link, in case the target site is unreachable or goes permanently offline.

Comment: Thanks! Getting the hang of it. :)

Answer (score 0):

Looks like the issue was fixed in the code ([gather_keys_oauth2.py](https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit/pull/72)) a week or so ago, but I couldn't find the documentation how to use the fixed code.

Looking for simple example if possible.

> @orcasgit/orcas-developers Please review. This should get the OAuth2 authentication working again. Works in my testing.

Comment: Looks like they updated their docs with that bug fix. I think you can find the info you need here: https://github.com/orcasgit/python-fitbit/blob/master/docs/index.rst